# How to prevent function to double animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation

In my plugin I handle animations by passing methods in external functions.

Firstly I have to check if the sidebars exists:

```
var left  = cfg.left.selector,
    right = cft.right.selector; 

function Sidebar( e ) {
        if ( e == undefined ) {
            console.log( "WARNING: A (or more) sidebar(s) has been left behind" );
        } else {
            var align, sbw, marginA, marginB, $sbRight, $sbLeft,
                $sidebar = $( e );
```

Once I'm sure that the sidebars (or maybe just one ) exists I define the variables I need to animate all elements:

```
            switch ( e == cfg.right.selector ) {
                case true:
                    align    = "right";
                    marginA  = "margin-right";
                    marginB  = "margin-left";
                    $sbRight = $( cfg.right.selector );
                    break;
                case false:
                    align    = "left";
                    marginA  = "margin-left";
                    marginB  = "margin-right";
                    $sbLeft  = $( cfg.left.selector );
                    break;
            }

        var def       = cfg[align], //new path to options
            $opener   = $( def.opener ),
            sbMaxW    = def.width,
            gap       = def.gap,
            winMaxW   = sbMaxW + gap,
            $elements = //a very long selector,
            w         = $( window ).width();

        //defining sbw variable
        if ( w < winMaxW ) {
            sbw = w - gap;
        } else {
            sbw = sbMaxW;
        }

        //setting $sidebar initial position and style
        var initialPosition = {
            width: sbw,
            zIndex: cfg.zIndex
        };
        initialPosition[marginA] = -sbw;
        $sidebar.css( initialPosition );
```

And here are the animations. They are handled as external functions. The first animation works really good. It does its job:

```
        //Animate $elements to open the $sidebar
        var animateStart = function() {
            var ssbw = $sidebar.width();
                animation = {};

            animation[marginA] = '+=' + ssbw;
            animation[marginB] = '-=' + ssbw;

            $elements.each(function() {
                $( this ).animate( animation, {
                    duration: duration,
                    easing: easing,
                    complete: function() {
                        $( 'body, html' ).attr( 'data-' + dataName, 'overflow' );
                        maskDiv.fadeIn();
                    }
                });
            });
        },
```

but the second one is doubled when two sidebars exist!! I need to retrieve the `.wrapper` offset and then move `$elements` according to its value. So I thought that it works as in the first animation function, and that it would be as simple as there:

```
            animationReset = function() {
                var offset = $wrapper.offset().left;
                    reset = {};

                console.log( offset );
```

Console returns two time the value so the animation in doubled.

```
                reset[marginA] = '-=' + offset;
                reset[marginB] = '+=' + offset;

                $elements.each(function() {
                    $( this ).animate( reset, {
                        duration: duration,
                        easing: easing,
                        complete: function() {
                            maskDiv.fadeOut(function() {
                                $( 'body, html' ).removeAttr( 'data-' + dataName );
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            };
```

So now I run the animations on click functions.

```
        $( $opener ).click( animateStart );
        maskDiv.click( animationReset );

    }
}
```

And finally I pass the values running the main function two times.

```
Sidebar( left );
Sidebar( right );
```

Why it worked on the first animation and then it is doubled in the second animation?

DEMO: http://dcdeiv.github.io/amazing-sidebar/

FULL CODE: https://github.com/dcdeiv/amazing-sidebar/blob/master/development/jquery.amazingsidebar.js

Comment: animationReset seems to be the one which is being run twice.. at least, just testing it, but it looks like it is

Comment: Yes! **animateReset** is run twice and I don't know why!

Comment: Wait a second, is maskDiv a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are adding two times the click event at

```
maskDiv.click( animationReset );
```

since maskDiv is the main div of the website and there is only one, but the looping is doing it twice.

Try to take that out of the loops definitions and do it only once, but maybe it is difficult because it is defined inside the `Sidebar` function, so you can try to create a global variable at the top and, after the first click event is added, not add any more:

At the top:

```
var notAdded = true;
```

In the sidebar function:

```
$( $opener ).click( animateStart );
if(notAdded){
    maskDiv.click( animationReset );    
    notAdded = false;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It worked but I don't understand what `notAdded` really does!

Comment: `notAdded` avoid you to bind the reset action more than once on the mask. After first execution, the flag truns to false, and during next execution, the bind will be skiped.

Comment: In your code, you call two times to Sidebar function (one with left and another with right). In both callings you are adding the animationReset function to the maskDiv, so when you click on the div, the function is also called twice.

The notAdded just check if it is not added (by default is not added, so it is true), so it adds the function animationReset to the click event of maskDiv and set notAdded to false, so the second time you call the Sidebar function the notAdded is false and the animationReset is not added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cause :

```
var maskDiv = $( 'body' ).children().filter(function(){
                return $( this ).data( dataName ) === 'mask' ;
            });
```

and

```
 maskDiv.click( animationReset );
```

You have two data-named 'mask' elements on the body.

So the click action is setup on both when you call the Sidebar function.

As you call it twice, you got the reset action run twice ...

---

EDIT : I was wrong : you have only one mask, but as it is used by both sidebars, you still have a double setup on it.

Comment: It seems like the `Sidebar` loop calls the `maskDiv` twice since I'm calling two times the loop.

Comment: Yes. It is. @RubenRAparicio better analysed the pb (you have only one mask for both sidebars) ... and he gave a pretty good solution.